# How to get output to show only CMD with ps -u UserName

Tags: linux, unix, ps

If I do the command in Linux:

```
ps -u UserName
```

Then I get a list of things in format of:

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

How can I get output to show only CMD(filenames)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk work like charm:

```
ps -u username | awk '{print $4}'
```

awk by default uses space delimiter , so you will get four fields that is PID is $1, TTY is $2, TIME is $3 and CMD is $4, so in my code i have printed only $4 to give you CMD fields.

Comment: The reason I gave an answer with the cut command is that with the awk, as you provided it here, you will loose arguments given to the binaries in the CMD column. But then again, maybe the problem was to get the filename alone.

Comment: yep the problem is to get only filename, that why i said, it works like charm.

Answer (score 5):

```
ps -o cmd -u UserName
```

More information here: https://superuser.com/questions/568245/how-to-get-only-the-user-the-pid-and-the-command-run-for-a-specific-process-u

Comment: +1  Cogent and portable.  `ps -o cmd= -u _UserName_` to get rid of column headers.

Answer (score 0):

Something as the following should work,

```
ps -u UserName | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 6-
```

The 6- should be replaced with the column your CMD is on.